# Replacing a part of particular lines of a file in perl

Tags: regex, oracle, perl, replace

I have a file which essentially has tags in it in each of its lines. 
Example:

`<stock_name>Abc Inc.</stock_name>
 <stock_value>123.456</stock_value>
........`

I have a database table which has records telling (new) stock value for the stocks. 
The database table has say 2 columns: `stock_name and stock_value`

I need to scan this database table and for each stock_name in the table, I need to replace the `<stock_value>xxx</stock_value>` with `<stock_value>yyy</stock_value>` against the appropriate `<stock_name>` in the file (xxx=existing stock_value in the file; yyy=new stock_value retrieved from the database for the particular stock). Could anyone help me on this please?

PS: This is not a homework. I am in the middle of writing a perl script to modify the file. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Does it have to be perl? this seems well suited to sed.

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to replace the text thereby modifying the file. I don't want to write to a new file.

Comment: Two things:
1) I don't want to alter the original sequence of <stock_name> and <stock_value> after modifying the <stock_value>.

2) Since the value retrieved from the database table may not necessarily be in the same order/sequence as that in the file. Hence writing to a new file is not feasible/too cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

If your markup is *guaranteed* to be `<tag>value</tag>`, then this will replace the values using a hash keyed off of the tag name:

```
my %table = (
    stock_name => 'xxx',
    stock_value => 'yyy',
);

$file = s/<([^>\/]*)>[^<]*/<$1>$table{$1}/g;
```